# distribute data in both increment and decrement order

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file which has n number of rows, i want it's data to be distributed in 7 files as per below order

** my input file has n number of rows, this is just an example.

Input file

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
1
5
16
17
.
.
28
```

Output file

```
 1  2  3  4  5 6  7
14 13 12 11 10 9  8 
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
28 27 26 25 24 23 22
```

so if i open the first file it should have rows

```
1
14
15
28
```

similarly if i open the second file it should have rows

```
2
13
16
27
```

similarly output for the other files as well.

Can anybody please help, with below code it is doing what is required but not in required order.

```
awk '{print > ("te1234"++c".txt");c=(NR%n)?c:0}' n=7 test6.txt
```

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

Comment: Replace the `. .` in your sample input with real values so we have something to test a potential solution against without having to do that work ourselves. Also fix the `1\n5\n` in your data. You could make it a briefer example anyway though.

Comment: Get rid of the block that starts with `Output file` - it's a huge red herring that can cause people to think you want such an output file and so lead to us creating solutions you don't actually need.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed sample of Input_file totally different so adding this solution now, again this is written and tested with shown samples only.

***With `xargs` + single `awk`:*** (recommended one)

```
xargs -n7 < Input_file | 
awk '
FNR%2!=0{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print $i >> (i".txt")
    close(i".txt")
  }
  next
}
FNR%2==0{
   for(i=NF;i>0;i--){
     count++
     print $i >> (count".txt")
     close(i".txt")
   }
   count=""
}'
```

***Initial solution:***

```
xargs -n7 < Input_file | 
awk '
FNR%2==0{
  for(i=NF;i>0;i--){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
  }
  $i=val
  val=""
}
1' | 
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print $i >> (i".txt")
    close(i".txt")
  }
}'
```

Above could be done with single `awk` too will add `xargs` + `awk`(single) solution in few mins too.

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i >> (i".txt");close(i".txt")}}' Input_file
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13- It 's not giving any output.

Comment: @LaxmiDevi, this worked fine for me for given example(it creates files like 1.txt, 2.txt and so on), is your actual Input_file same as shown samples?

Comment: It's  not dividing files in 7 part, also output we are getting is not correct.

Comment: @LaxmiDevi, if I am reading your question correctly you want file's output column wise right? I mean all line's 1st columns in 1.txt all 2nd columns in 2.txt and so on from your samples it looks like that. Please confirm once?

Comment: @LaxmiDevi, your question is completely changed now, we need to add another solution now all together.

Comment: @LaxmiDevi, Could you please check my EDIT solution and lemme know if this helps you?

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, but it's not distributing the output in 7 different files as requested above.

Comment: @LaxmiDevi, Not clear, output comes in your shown form, could you please update your question because EDIT solution gives output as per shown samples, please update your question and lemme know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13- I have refined my question, so each file should have some rows as requested in the question, so if i open first file it should list
```
1
14
15
28
```

Comment: @LaxmiDevi, Could you please do lemme know if EDIT solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

The output file counter could descend for each second group of seven:

```
awk 'FNR%n==1 {asc=!asc}
    {
        out="te1234" (asc ? ++c : c--) ".txt";
        print >> out;
        close(out)
    }' n=7 test6.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls
file    tst.awk

$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = (cnt % 2 ? $1 sep rec : rec sep $1); sep=FS }
!(NR%n) {
    ++cnt
    nf = split(rec,flds)
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        out = "te1234" i ".txt"
        print flds[i] >> out
        close(out)
    }
    rec=sep=""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v n=7 -f tst.awk file
```

.

```
$ ls
file        te12342.txt te12344.txt te12346.txt tst.awk
te12341.txt te12343.txt te12345.txt te12347.txt

$ cat te12341.txt
1
14
15
28

$ cat te12342.txt
2
13
16
27
```

If you can have input that's not an exact multiple of `n` then move the code that's currently in the `!(NR%n)` block into a function and call that function there and in an `END` section.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel  'echo {1}~14w file{1}; echo {2}~14w file{1}' ::: {1..7} :::+ {14..8} |
sed -n -f - file && 
paste file{1..7}
```

Create a sed script to write files named filen where n is 1 thru 7 (see above first set of parameters in the parallel command and also in the paste command).

The sed script uses the `n~m` address where `n` is the starting address and `m` is the modulo thereafter.

The distributed files are created first and the paste command then joins them all together to produce a single output file (tab separated by default, use paste `-d` option to get desired delimiter).

Alternative using Bash & sed:

```
for ((n=1,m=14;n<=7;n++,m--));do echo "$n~14w file$n";echo "$m~14w file$n";done |
sed -nf - file && 
paste file{1..7}
```